# Sizing Flex DataGridColumns(Dynamic number)

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I have a DataGrid that has between 4-10 columns. I want the columns to be of width '50'. I have already set the width attribute in MXML. I am using "colName.hide = true" to hide various columns depending on whether I have data. I find that my columns expand when I have less columns. Is there a way to set the max width of a column or force it to keep the same width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leave one column with undefined width - it will stretch when parent (grid) will be resized.

Or, you should recalculate and apply width of the greed dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Why not just resize the width of the datagrid itself to 50 * amtOfCols when columns are hidden and shown?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing yesterday. It isn't as elegant as I would have liked but it worked:) I would have preferred to keep it the width and height of the datagrid in percent form. I couldn't do that because it kept going crazy.